# CakePHP Find on CakeSession Failing

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to read from the sessions table and display on a page in CakePHP. I can load the CakeSession model easy enough and even do a read on it, which works.

But when I do a find:

```
$sessions = $this->CakeSession->find('all');
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method CakeSession::find()
```

Any ideas on how to do a find on that model?

Comment: I didn't know it was a database model...

Comment: There is a model for it under lib>Cake>Model>Datasource>CakeSession.php. Unless that's not a model?

Comment: Far as I know it's a component, models in Cake relate directly to database tables. Hence your error, find it a database query

Comment: @tgurske It's not a model. According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions you have to specify a model you can then use to query the table.

Comment: I was assuming that the component had a model since "read" worked but I guess I was wrong. I created a model and it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a model and it works, and didn't break anything else. Thanks for your help scrawler and dhofstet!